# How to pass parameters in a Python Dispatch Table

Tags: python, dispatch-table

I am trying to construct a dispatch the following way:

```
def run_nn(type=None):
    print type, 'nn'
    return

def run_svm(type=None):
    print type, 'svm'
    return


action = {'nn' : run_nn( type=None),
          'svm' : run_svm(type=None),}
```

I want the function to be executed *only* when called with something like:

```
 action.get('nn',type='foo')
```

With expectation it to print:

```
foo nn
```

But it breaks giving:

```
TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments
```

What's the right way to do it?

Furthermore, two functions `run_nn()` and `run_svm()` were executed without even being called. I don't want that. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling the functions while building the dictionary. You should instead put the function objects in the dict without calling them. And afterwards, `get` the appropriate function from the dict and call it with the keyword argument.

What you want is:

```
action = {'nn' : run_nn,
          'svm' : run_svm,}
...
action.get('nn')(type='foo') # get function object from dict and then call it.
```

I'll suggest you use `action['nn']` over `action.get('nn')` since you're not specifying any default *callable* in the `get` method; the `get` method returns `None` when you don't specify one. A `KeyError` is much more intuitive than a `TypeError` *NoneType object is not callable* in this scenario.

On another note, you can drop those `return` statements as you aren't actually returning anything. Your function will still *return* without them.

BTW, I have the feeling your function(s) want to change behavior depending on `type` (although your `type` is counter-intuitive as it is always a string). In any case, you may have a look at [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). That'll transform your function(s) into a [single-dispatch generic function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) with the possibility to create several overloaded implementations.

Finally, although `type` does make for a good argument name, you will run into problems when you need to use the builtin `type` in your function.